# .NET... How to TDD with flat files

Tags: c#, .net, tdd, agile

I have a project where most of the challenges are to ensure software works correctly with flat text files outputted by several external systems.

Mangement made decision to introduce Agile and TDD as a particular implementation.

I found that mocking input from the flat files makes no sense because the main issue to resolve is exactly correct work with those particular files.

E.g. if output in external systems change the unit test must fail.

Unit-testing the code abstracted from the files makes very little sense and create very little business value (as the abstracted code will take lots of time to be abstracted and in the reality will produce a hundred one line methods).

Just want to reiterate - the challenge is to keep a tight tab on the software being able to work with flat files and TDD is to make this verifiable at any time.

What would be the suggestions? How this can be organised, defined, implemented?

Comment: May be it will be easier if I narrow the question. Is there any automation software which can be used to work with flat files as input/output of unit tests.. We are going to use VS2010 unit tests and Moq for mocking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a specification for the format of the flat files?

If so, you should include sample files that have each feature of the specification, and write a test for each feature.

If the flat files do not conform to a specification, you can't really do TDD on them - you might always have a new file with an unknown in it. In this case you would have to write your own specification, (based on observation/research) and TDD against that. But you would still be open to unknown data breaking your code.

The moral? Make sure you have at least a working practice specification.

Comment: we dont have working practice specifications. that what I am trying to create to be honest. the so called team leader has no idea what he is talking about. he want us to implement everything and he will only report to the top manager. simple.

Answer (score 6):

Include sample files in your test project, and test using those. I tend to build the files into the test assembly and use [`Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc4235zt.aspx) to pass it into the code. Using a `Stream` or `TextReader` in the API also means you can do very small tests using `MemoryStream` or `StringReader` with the data in the test code itself. (Unless you need to worry about detecting encodings, using a `TextReader` is probably more appropriate than a `Stream`.)

You could do it *all* with `StringReader`, but in my experience if you end up with several lines of test data it can get quite confusing - separate files can make it easier to see the data involved.

Note that this *doesn't* check that the output of the external systems hasn't changed - as Pontus says, that would involve system/integration tests. However, you don't want to do *most* of your testing at that level in my experience. You should have a mixture of tests at different levels, but the higher the level of the test, the longer it's likely to take to run - and the harder it may be to set up.

You *may* want tests which *only* test the external systems: have a piece of sample data which you expect to receive from the external systems, and have one unit test of *your* code that tests it behaves appropriately, and one "external" test which calls the external systems and checks that they produce that exact file. That way, you'll very quickly be able to tell if a failure is due to your code changing or the external systems changing.

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't sound like test driven development or unit testing at all: what you're describing is integration monitoring and/or [system testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_testing) of the external systems. Are you describing a production environment or a development environment scenario? If the text files change, who should adapt (your consumer or the producing system)?

Whatever you do, make sure you have a clearly defined **contract** specifying the format and content of the text files which form the interface between your system and the external ones. If possible, implement monitoring functions in the production environments which trigger a warning if a source system deviates from the contract.

Comment: developers even senior dont have say on that. and nothing is possible to define in the environment. so yes it is integration rather but has to be implemented to produce TDD like results... unfortunately I cant change that... also - the consumer is always has to change.

Comment: OK, your management doesn't know what they're talking about. That's bad. And not uncommon. OTOH, are they going to know what you actually do? Whatever they say they want, can you find a way to do what they really need instead?

Comment: thats different. what is has to be achieved is always known. but that is up to BAs not managers. BAs not interested in what way (TDD or casio calculator or scrap paper).

Answer (score 1):

From a .NET perspective, flat file are essentially **strings**, so I would design most of my API around testing input and output strings.

If those strings get too large, you can embed them in separate files, but it is always better testing practice to **reduce** each test case to the bare minimum necessary to reproduce/exetute a certain feature.